# Archive folders only with today's date name

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have all my backups in one directory and they are stored and created with %date% variable so today's backup folder name is 2016-12-12.
Now I need to create script to archive only folders with today's date (when scrips is executed), but I don't know how to do this:

```
FOR /D %%i IN (c:\backup\%date%) DO "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -mx=9 -sdel -x!*.7z "%%i.7z" "%%i\"
```

this not work.

Comment: You should show us exactly how you build the backup folder names out of `%date%`...

Comment: I simply use md c:\backup\"%date%"\ 
and then robocopy from source to created folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad "C:\backup\*%date%*" ') do ......
```

That is, perform a directory list in `/b` basic form (names only) `/ad` of directories only matching `C:\backup\*%date%*` and assign the result to `%%i`.

Note that this will only work as intended for date formats that don't contain characters that are illegal in a directoryname like `/` or that contain spaces.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad "C:\Backup\*%date%*" ') DO "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -mx=9 -sdel -x!*.7z "%%i.7z" "%%i\"`

Error
Incorrect command line

Comment: If you simply `echo %%i`, you should see the values that have been assigned to `%%i` . I don't know what format you are using for `%date%` so I can't test this routine. I can only use the data you've presented, which seems to indicate that your setting of  `%date%` will show (eg) "2016-12-12"

Comment: `echo %%i` give me `%i`,
`%date%` - it give me date like 2016-12-13

so how should I correct this script?